# Absolute center and autonilpotent $p$-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $G'$, $Z(G)$, $\Phi(G)$ and $\exp(G)$ denotes the commutator subgroup, the center, the Frattini subgroup and exponent of $G$.
The absolute center of $G$ denoted by $L(G)$ is the set of all those elements of $G$ which are fixed by every automorphism. i.e. $$L(G) = \lbrace g\in G\mid \alpha(g)=g,\forall\alpha\in Aut(G)\rbrace$$. or $$L(G) = \lbrace g\in G\mid [g,\alpha]=1,\forall\alpha\in Aut(G)\rbrace ,$$ where $[g,\alpha]=g^{-1}\alpha(g)$ is called the autocommutator of $g$ and $\alpha.$
Clearly $L(G)$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$.
Inductively, for all $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,..., \alpha_{n}\in Aut(G)$,
$$[g,\alpha_1, \alpha_2,..., \alpha_{n}] = [[g,\alpha_1, \alpha_2,..., \alpha_{n-1}], \alpha_n]$$ is the autocommutator of $g, \alpha_1, \alpha_2,..., \alpha_{n}$.

Let $L_1(G)=L(G)$, for $n\geq 2$, define $L_n(G)$ inductively as

$L_n(G)$ = $\lbrace g\in G\mid [g,\alpha_1, \alpha_2,..., \alpha_{n}] = 1$, for all $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,..., \alpha_{n}\in Aut(G)\rbrace$.
A group $G$ is called autonilpotent of class $n$ if $n$ is the smallest natural number such that $L_n(G)=G$.
A $p$-group $G$ is said to be extraspecial if $G'=Z(G)=\Phi(G)$ is of order $p$. It is well known that nilpotency class of extraspecial group is $2$.  This observation raises the following natural question.

Does there exist finite $p$-group $G$ (with $|G| \geq p^5$) of autonilpotency class $2$ such that $G'=L(G)=\Phi(G)$ is of order $p$?

or

Does there exist a family of finite $p$-group $G$ (with $|G| \geq p^5$) of autonilpotency class $2$ such that $G'=L(G)=\Phi(G)$ is of order $p$?